# Comparing 3 fields in the same record in Access

Tags: ms-access

I have 3 fields that I am trying to compare the values for in Access. Would be easy if there was a SMALL and LARGE function, but there is not.  I need to derive the small and large values to run analysis off it.  Any help appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Show the table structure and your attempt.

Comment: What should these functions do?

Comment: 3 Fields: S&P NAIC, Moodys NAIC, and Fitch NAIC.  Each of these fields contains a value from: 0 - 100.  I need to write a calculated field to derive the 2 smallest of these 3 values for a query.

Comment: Based on this comment, it doesn't sound like what you are asking for is what was described in the question.

Comment: Jeremy: I have this keyed into the new query build: The Table name = STEP 1 Holdings Rating Mapping and A, B, C = S&P NAIC, Moodys NAIC, and FITCH NAIC respectively.

Comment: SELECT ID, max(Value) as MaxValue, min(Value) as MinValue
FROM (select ID, S&P NAIC as Value from STEP 1 Holdings Rating Mapping,
union all select ID, Moodys NAIC as Value from STEP 1 Holdings Rating Mapping,
union all select ID, Fitch NAIC as Value from from STEP 1 Holdings Rating Mapping)
Data Group by ID

Comment: I am getting the following error:  The SELECT statements includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect.

Comment: Any help appreciated. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach. Given a table named Table with columns ID, A, B and C:

```
select ID, max(Value) as MaxValue, min(Value) as MinValue
from (
    select ID, A as Value from Table
    union all select ID, B as Value from Table
    union all select ID, C as Value from Table
) Data
group by ID
```

Comment: should select ID be the table name or the name of all 3 columns A,B,c? thx

Comment: ID should be the table's primary key or a way to uniquely identify a record. You may need to provide more than one column to uniquely identify your record.